# Cannot enter Latin-1 characters in tmux

Tags: tmux, character-set

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, I cannot enter Latin-1 characters  (like Umlaute ä etc.) in tmux. I tried the packaged tmux, self-installed tmux 2.1 and 2.2. Furthermore, if I 'view' a file in tmux, they just disappear.
My settings are:
LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
LC_CTYPE=en_US.ISO-8859-1
LC_TIME=en_US.ISO-8859-1

Note that I can enter Latin-1 characters in all terminals
I have installed.